# Recompiling libiconv, gettext undefined symbols occurring after an already successful install

Tags: c++, macos, shared-libraries, libtool, pkg-config

Main Obvious Error "`Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64`"

> How do I get these to compile successfully again?

The Operating System is Mac OS X. Have installed multiple programs from 
their sources. Noticed the problem after having installed:

- `binutils` **v2.25**,
- `libtool` **v2.4.6**,
- `glib` **v2.45.2**,     OR
- `pkgconfig` **v0.28**

Before installing any of the above, recompiling `libiconv` and `gettext` 
produced no errors and both successfully installed multiple times.

`pkg-config --list-all` does not display `libiconv` nor `gettext`
(if that at all means anything significant)

`libiconv` and `gettext` are direct copies from theiy're respective sites.

http://www.gnu.org/software/libiconv/#downloading

```
iconv --version
iconv (GNU libiconv 1.14)
Copyright (C) 2000-2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
Written by Bruno Haible.
```

http://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/gettext/

```
gettext --version
gettext (GNU gettext-runtime) 0.19.5.1
Copyright (C) 1995-1997, 2000-2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
Written by Ulrich Drepper.
```

### `libiconv` v1.14

Trying to use `libiconv` in a simple `.c` file:

```
#include <iconv.h>
// works: gcc -m32 -I/usr/local/include -liconv -o test-iconv.exe test-iconv.c
// does NOT work: gcc -I/usr/local/include -liconv -o test-iconv.exe test-iconv.c
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    iconv_t conv = iconv_open("ISO8859-1", "UTF-8");
    if (conv != (iconv_t) -1) {
    return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

If I do not specify `-m32` for `gcc` then I received the following error:

```
$ gcc -I/usr/local/include -liconv -o test-iconv.exe test-iconv.c
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_libiconv_open", referenced from:
      _main in ccr9tTic.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

**Attempting to recompile `libiconv`**

```
libiconv-1.14 $ make distclean; ./configure --enable-extra-encodings \
  --with-libiconv-prefix=/usr/local/include; make V=1 
...
...
...
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DEXEEXT=\"\" -I. -I.. -I../lib  -I../intl \
    -DDEPENDS_ON_LIBICONV=1 -D DEPENDS_ON_LIBINTL=1 -I/usr/local/include  \
    -g -O2 -c strerror-override.c
rm -f libicrt.a
ar cru libicrt.a allocator.o areadlink.o careadlinkat.o malloca.o progname.o \
    safe-read.o width.o xmalloc.o xstrdup.o xreadlink.o canonicalize-lgpl.o \
    error.o lstat.o readlink.o stat.o strerror.o strerror-override.o
ranlib libicrt.a
cd src && make all
gcc -c -I. -I. -I.. -I../include -I./../include -I../srclib -I./../srclib \
    -I../lib -g -O2 -I/usr/local/include -DINSTALLDIR=\"/usr/local/bin\" \
    -DLOCALEDIR=\"/usr/local/share/locale\" ./iconv_no_i18n.c
/bin/sh ../libtool --mode=link gcc  -g -O2 iconv_no_i18n.o \
    ../srclib/libicrt.a ../lib/libiconv.la  -o iconv_no_i18n
libtool: link: gcc -g -O2 iconv_no_i18n.o -o .libs/iconv_no_i18n \
    ../srclib/libicrt.a ../lib/.libs/libiconv.dylib
ld: warning: ignoring file ../srclib/libicrt.a, file was built for archive 
    which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): ../srclib/libicrt.a
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
 "_program_name", referenced from:
     _main in iconv_no_i18n.o
     _usage in iconv_no_i18n.o
     _error in iconv_no_i18n.o
 "_rpl_strerror", referenced from:
     _error in iconv_no_i18n.o
 "_safe_read", referenced from:
     _convert in iconv_no_i18n.o
 "_set_program_name", referenced from:
     _main in iconv_no_i18n.o
 "_uc_width", referenced from:
     _update_line_column in iconv_no_i18n.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status 
make[1]: *** [iconv_no_i18n] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

### Information from `lipo`:

`architecture being linked (x86_64): ../srclib/libicrt.a`

```
libiconv-1.14 $ lipo -info srclib/libicrt.a
input file srclib/libicrt.a is not a fat file
Non-fat file: srclib/libicrt.a is architecture: x86_64
```

### `gettext` v0.19.5.1

```
gettext-0.19.5.1 $ make distclean; ./configure; make V=1
...
...
...
libtool: link: ( cd ".libs" && rm -f "libgnu.la" && ln -s "../libgnu.la" \
    "libgnu.la" )
Making all in src
gcc -DLOCALEDIR=\"/usr/local/share/locale\" -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..  -I. \
    -I. -I.. -I../intl -I./../intl -I../gnulib-lib -I./../gnulib-lib \
    -I/usr/local/include -DINSTALLDIR=\"/usr/local/bin\" -g -O2 -c -o \
    gettext-gettext.o `test -f 'gettext.c' || echo './'`gettext.c
/bin/sh ../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=link gcc \
    -DINSTALLDIR=\"/usr/local/bin\" -g -O2   -o gettext gettext-gettext.o \
    ../gnulib-lib/libgrt.a ../intl/libintl.la -L/usr/local/lib -liconv \
    -R/usr/local/lib  -Wl,-framework -Wl,CoreFoundation -L/usr/local/lib \
    -liconv -R/usr/local/lib  
libtool: link: gcc -DINSTALLDIR=\"/usr/local/bin\" -g -O2 -o .libs/gettext \
    gettext-gettext.o -Wl,-framework -Wl,CoreFoundation  \
    ../gnulib-lib/libgrt.a ../intl/.libs/libintl.dylib -L/usr/local/lib \
    -lc /usr/local/lib/libiconv.dylib
ld: warning: ignoring file ../gnulib-lib/libgrt.a, file was built for archive
    which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): ../gnulib-lib/libgrt.a
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_close_stdout", referenced from:
      _main in gettext-gettext.o
  "_error", referenced from:
      _main in gettext-gettext.o
  "_gnu_basename", referenced from:
      _main in gettext-gettext.o  "_program_name", referenced from:
      _main in gettext-gettext.o
      _usage in gettext-gettext.o
  "_proper_name", referenced from:
      _main in gettext-gettext.o
  "_rpl_getopt_long", referenced from:
      _main in gettext-gettext.o
  "_rpl_optarg", referenced from:
      _main in gettext-gettext.o
  "_rpl_optind", referenced from:
      _main in gettext-gettext.o
  "_set_program_name", referenced from:
      _main in gettext-gettext.o
  "_xmalloc", referenced from:
      _expand_escape in gettext-gettext.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[4]: *** [gettext] Error 1
make[3]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

### Information from `lipo`

`architecture being linked (x86_64): ../gnulib-lib/libgrt.a`

```
gettext-0.19.5.1 $ lipo -info gettext-runtime/gnulib-lib/libgrt.a 
input file gettext-runtime/gnulib-lib/libgrt.a is not a fat file
Non-fat file: gettext-runtime/gnulib-lib/libgrt.a is architecture: x86_64
```

Comment: `--with-libiconv-prefix=/usr/local/include` looks suspicious.

Comment: `iconv.h` is installed at `/usr/local/include`. I also have `-I/usr/local/include` for `gcc` in order for the `.c` file to have access for it.

Comment: For all the programs I haven't changed their `--prefix=`

Comment: From `./configure --help` on `libiconv` : `--with-libiconv-prefix[=DIR]  search for libiconv in DIR/include and DIR/lib`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be that you have alternative versions of gcc and ar installed and that they are in your path before the standard locations (/usr/bin).

I've had the same problem in the past and this post helped me troubleshoot and fix: https://www.unix.com/programming/253809-linker-errors-linking-files-os-x.html

Comment: This was it for me.  Setting AR and RANLIB to the versions in /usr/bin did the trick.