# When installing a library is it one of `ar`, `libtool`, `ranlib`, or other which decides if it's 32 or 64bit?

Tags: gcc, architecture, libtool, unix-ar, libiconv

> Snippet from [Recompiling libiconv, gettext undefined symbols occurring after an already successful install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31820672/) ; thought to make it its own question.

Trying to use `libiconv` in a simple `.c` file:

```
#include <iconv.h>
// works: gcc -m32 -I/usr/local/include -liconv -o test-iconv.exe test-iconv.c
// does NOT work: gcc -I/usr/local/include -liconv -o test-iconv.exe test-iconv.c
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    iconv_t conv = iconv_open("ISO8859-1", "UTF-8");
    if (conv != (iconv_t) -1) {
    return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

If I do not specify `-m32` for `gcc` then I received the following error:

```
$ gcc -I/usr/local/include -liconv -o test-iconv.exe test-iconv.c
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_libiconv_open", referenced from:
      _main in ccr9tTic.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: You are passing `-m32` to **gcc**, how does that not already answer your question?

Comment: Sorry, I'm attempting to keep the rest lf the programs 64bit. `libiconv` is one of their dependencies

Answer (score 0):

When you 'install' a library, the library has already been built and the installation cannot change whether it is a 32-bit or 64-bit library.

What controls whether a library is for 32-bit or 64-bit (or both, if you're on macOS Sierra or Mac OS X) is the way the object files are compiled.  If you compile with `gcc -m32`, the object files will be 32-bit and the library will be 32-bit; if you compile with `-m64`, they'll be 64-bit.  If you compile with neither option, you'll get a default behaviour, and the default depends on the platform and how the compiler was built.  If you're using one of the Mac operating systems, it is possible to compile both the 32-bit and 64-bit versions into a single object file, and then create a library that contains both 32-bit and 64-bit.

By the looks of it, you need to ensure that you compile `libiconv` with the 64-bit options.  You might need to use `./configure CC='gcc -m64' CXX=`g++ -m64`…` or something similar to force 64-bit compilations — it is a trick I sometimes use.

Comment: I guess the main issue I had was my system was supposedly only 32bit (the OS). Why would I have issues with compiling if the OS was already 32bit but the program `libiconv` was having problems compiling for "architecture x86_64"